# Require decorator in interface implementation

Tags: typescript, interface, decorator

I am looking to enforce that certain members of a `typescript` interface require decorators in their implementation.

Here is my example interface:

```
export interface InjectComponentDef<TComponent> {
  // TODO is it possible to make this only allow properties decorated with @Input()
  inputs: Partial<TComponent>, // & { @Input() [key: string]: any } my attempt to enforce decorator, invalid syntax 
  //... 
};
```

My goal would be give the class below, I want to disallow the `notAnInput` property from being included in an `InjectComponentDef.inputs` implementation

```
export class MyComponent {
   public @Input() isAnInput: string;
   public notAnInput: string;
}
...
let x:InputComponentDef<MyComponent>=
{
    inputs: {
        isAnInput:'all good',
        notAnInput:'no good', // I want this to throw a compile time error because it is not decorated with @Input
    }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this within typescript at **compile time**?

Answer (score 1):

From [the TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

> The expression for the class decorator will be called as a function at runtime, with the constructor of the decorated class as its only argument.

And:

> [they] evaluate to a function that will be called at runtime with information about the decorated declaration.

This sounds like decorators are not meant to be used at compile time at all.
So even it it works using some workaround, the approach might not be correct from a design perspective.

Bottom line, your use case looks like something you cannot really catch at compile time.

One thing to think about: why do you need to enforce `@Input()` at all? Think about some child object which sets data for `notAnInput` itself, that might be perfectly valid depending on your use case.